# Using older Desktop environment for newer distro's

Tags: gnome, security, desktop-environments

I simply hate gnome 3, how inflexible it is, how slow it got and I was wondering that can you replace gnome 3 with gnome 2 in newer distro's (say for example Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS)?

Are there any security risks/flaws in using older Desktop environments on a newer operating system?

Comment: why not use Mate? it is *designed* for the purpose of providing a Gnome2-like experience with modern tech.

Comment: @ashvatthama One thing I really like about gnome is its application launcher, UI and user-friendly design. I've seen Mate but really didn't like its design.

Comment: @Daniel MATE is almost identical to GNOME 2. If you don't like the design, you can try something else.

Comment: GNOME2 used GTK2.  Most of GTK2 is EOL, the only parts of it still maintained are the parts used by `gimp` which hasn't completed it's port to GTK3.  LXDE used GTK2, however Lubuntu switched to Qt5 & LXQt with 18.10, MATE switched to GTK3 so long ago I can't recall which release, and XFCE was fully GTK3 by 19.10. GTK2 is dead, or probably more accurate on life-support, so GNOME2 is not possible, or at least not advisable.

Comment: @Daniel by "its application launcher" you mean the fullscreen launcher in GNOME 3? well, there's some third-party apps which offer a replacement.

Comment: FYI:   Opinion, but MATE is a good suggestion. MATE forked GNOME2 at the outset, and then stripped out the legacy code creating a faster GNOME2 fork [clone]. Since then they've added features, and ported to GTK3, so yes MATE is now heavier (GTK3 is quite a bit heavier than GTK2, why LXDE *devs* blogged they moved to Qt5/LXQt), but still MATE is a very good compromise and well worth a try.

Comment: *If you're using a single core pentium 4/M from say 2003-2005, MATE with GTK3 is slowish, but anything more modern can cope quite easily in my testing; but you'll be on 18.04 in that case anyway and not 20.04 as those boxes are x86/32-bit only. Lighter environments exist yes, even lighter than LXQt, but few of us actually use devices that limited (eg. 1GB) in RAM, with single-core cpus.  I'd suggest sticking with a Ubuntu flavor, https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

GNOME2 used GTK2.

Most of GTK2 is EOL, the only parts of it still maintained are the parts used by `gimp` which hasn't completed it's port to GTK3.

Lubuntu used LXDE which used GTK2, however Lubuntu switched to Qt5 & LXQt with Lubuntu 18.10

Ubuntu-MATE & the MATE desktop switched to GTK3 so long ago I can't recall which release (15.10 maybe, if not 16.04)

Xubuntu uses XFCE, which had fully ported to GTK3 by Xubuntu 19.10.

GTK2 is dead, or probably more accurately on *life-support*, so GNOME2 is not possible, or **at least not advisable** (security-wise, with very large portions of it *abandon-ware*)