# How to use Gnome old version with Ubuntu latest version

Tags: gnome, gnome2

how do i install Ubuntu 23.10 with gnome old version 2.18 the current version of gnome is difficult to use, i want to use gnome old version with ubuntu latest version.

I am reading help file given in ubuntu, see the attachment picture.

it says install package "gnome-shell-entensions" but i did not fine this package. here is the search result

```
gnome-shell/mantic-updates 45.1-0ubuntu1 amd64 [upgradable from: 45.0-1ubuntu2]
  graphical shell for the GNOME desktop
gnome-shell-common/mantic-updates 45.1-0ubuntu1 all [upgradable from: 45.0-1ubuntu2]
  common files for the GNOME graphical shell
gnome-shell-extension-appindicator/mantic,now 57-1 all [installed,automatic]
gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons-ng/mantic,now 46+really47.0.5-1 all [installed,automatic]
gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock/mantic-updates 87ubuntu2 all [upgradable from: 87ubuntu1]
gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-tiling-assistant/mantic,now 44-1ubuntu1 all [installed,automatic]
  file manager and graphical shell for GNOME
yaru-theme-gnome-shell/mantic,now 23.10.0-0ubuntu2 all [installed,automatic]
  Display graphical dialog boxes from shell scripts
  Display graphical dialog boxes from shell scripts (common files)
```

i am unable to use gnome classic session too.

[Ubuntu Help is Wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/es0uy.png)

Comment: Your best solution will be to replace the GNOME desktop with another that uses the GTK or GNOME/GIMP Toolkit and gives you what you actually want; be that MATE, Xfce etc.  MATE is probably your best bet (*given it's existence is to use the current toolkit but provide a GNOME 2 like experience for those that wanted it*)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using older Desktop environment for newer distro's](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1277908/using-older-desktop-environment-for-newer-distros)

Comment: by mistake I tagged ubuntu version. is there any deb package available, which convert gnome version (which is ubuntu 23 uses) look and feel to mate or gnome 2?

Comment: You can `sudo apt install mate-desktop` to install the MATE desktop; the versions of your libraries/toolkits installed on your system will not run the older GNOME Desktop; so for GNOME all you can do is logout, and re-login using the *GNOME Classic* desktop which uses the *modern* libs/tk & acts somewhat like what older GNOME2 is.  Those are your best options (outside of Xfce etc... LXDE is still a GTK2 desktop but may or may not be what you're after though)

Comment: please read question again, i had attached a picture. thank you

Comment: There seem to be two separate issues here: 1) Question about how to install an older version of Gnome, and 2) Complaint that Desktop Help is stale. #1 is readily answerable here. #2 should be a bug report.

Comment: Have you tried installing `gnome-shell-extensions` ie. `gnome-shell-extensions | 45.0-1          | mantic/universe        | source, all`  as this is what I believe your additional error message is asking you to do.

Comment: I run this command "sudo apt install mate-desktop" but mate desktop not installed. i used "sudo apt install tasksel" then "sudo tasksel install mate-desktop" this install mate 1.26 version.

Comment: @guiverc I have installed debian-live-7.7.0-amd64-gnome-desktop.iso on virtual machine, on my physical machine i have ubuntu 14 installed. from debine7.7 i copied gnome-panel file from /usr/bin/ and past in my physical machine, and it's dependencies.  i am successfully see panel and menus and clock. but i am still unable to add "battery,username" in the panel

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and [*official* flavors of Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/desktop/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.   *Debian is off-topic here as its not Ubuntu*  Ubuntu 14.04 LTS is years past EOSS thus is also off-topic here, http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/05/02/ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr-reached-end-of-life-on-april-25-2019-esm-available/  FYI: Debian 7 itself is EOL - https://www.debian.org/News/2018/20180601

Answer (score 0):

You cannot downgrade GNOME version, and there is no workaround for that.

However, you can use [Ubuntu MATE](https://ubuntu-mate.org/), which uses MATE Desktop instead of GNOME. MATE was developed as a continuation of the GNOME 2 desktop (just because the GNOME's new UI was very different and didn't suit many users' needs), and has very similar user interface.

[image]

Comment: I had downlaoded ubuntu mate from https://releases.ubuntu-mate.org/ these two isos 1.https://releases.ubuntu-mate.org/archived/14.04/amd64/ubuntu-mate-14.04.2-LTS-desktop-amd64.iso    2.https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-mate/releases/23.10/release/ubuntu-mate-23.10-desktop-amd64.iso both isos are currpt i am unable to boot these isos, 2 one give error lightdm service not started

Comment: 1 gave error "invalid or currpt kernel image"

Comment: Please give 22.04 LTS a try. Also, verify the checksums of the ISOs before flashing it to an USB drive.